# How to get questions higher than ID

Tags: support

How can I get questions sorted by Question_Id in descending? (Sorted by creation is working) and how to get questions higher than given ID (or higher than last questions creation), my idea is to get only those new questions which are not in DOM yet.

I am new to API and learning to use API with JavaScript. I have tried `/questions` & `/search`

Answer (score 1):

If all you're looking to do is get questions that were asked *after* a certain date, then simply use the `fromdate` parameter. According to the API docs:

> **fromdate** – Unix timestamp of the minimum creation date on a returned item.
>       unix epoch date, range [0, 253,402,300,799]

By specifying a timestamp for this parameter, you ensure that all questions returned will have a creation date greater than or equal to the timestamp.

Comment: Does this implies that a question with later date will have greater ID?

Comment: @Eimantas: This is true in most cases.